# Using gmap as exposed filter for proximity search

Tags: drupal, view, location

I'd like to click on the map and get the nearest nodes, stored in the system.

I've installed modules: location, gmap, views.
I've created two nodes with location information.
I've created a view with exposed filter: proximity search

Now i can see the map, but i cannot see any search result if i click on that map.. why?

Comment: share more details about what you have done in the view. Possibly export the view and paste the code here, so we what you are upto.